# jQuery.each() to limit number of table data per row

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to display table data using jQuery.ajax(). Everything seems to be functioning properly, but I want an output that will display 3 table data per table row. I have five data namely A, B, C, D, E. The output that I want should look something like this:

```
A B C
D E
```

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'php/init.php?display-images',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var max_rows = 3;
        var row_counter = 0;
        $('#tbl-mydesigns').append('<tr>');
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            while(row_counter < max_rows){
                $('#tbl-mydesigns tr').append('<td>'+item.imagename+'</td>');
                row_counter++;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However, it gives me this output:

```
A A A
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cycle inside another cycle. And you must append new tr after 3 pieces of data. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: 'php/init.php?display-images',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
      var max_cols = 3;
      $('#tbl-mydesigns').append('<tr></tr>');
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
         $('#tbl-mydesigns tr:last').append('<td>'+data[i].imagename+'</td>');
         if((i+1) % max_col == 0){
            $('#tbl-mydesigns').append('<tr></tr>');
         }
      }
      for(;i % max_col != 0;i++){
         $('#tbl-mydesigns tr:last').append('<td></td>');
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: row_counter is needed. if row_counter is removed it will display (Top: A B Bottom: C D E)

Comment: I edit my answer once more now it works :) sry for previous mistake

Comment: This will not produce a valid HTML structure when the length of your data is not exactly N * 3. (where N is the row number). And you are using the name 'row' for columns - very confusing.

Comment: Yes, that was true. New code produces valid code. And i rename variable to max_cols. Thanks for corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You need some re-organization because the item variable is NOT changed in your while cycle, so of course it will display the same A value. And since you are not resetting your counter to zero, it will not start to print new columns.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: 'php/init.php?display-images',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    var max_columns    = 3;
    var current_column = 0;

    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        if (current_column == 0) {
            $('#tbl-mydesigns').append('<tr>');
        }

        if (item.imagename) {
            $('#tbl-mydesigns tr:last').append('<td>' + item.imagename + '</td>');
        } else {
            $('#tbl-mydesigns tr:last').append('<td></td>');
        }

        current_column++;

        if (current_column == max_columns) {
            current_column = 0;
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Great *comment*... now if only our compilers could take English  as input :) Please add the code you suggest..